# How to make callbacks in Android. Other than using StartActivityForResult

Tags: android

Lets say I have 10 activities in backstack. How can a change in some 10th activity in the backstack(which is an instance of activity A) will  trigger a change in 2nd activity in the backstack(which is also an instance of activity A).

The reason I cannot use `StartActivityForResult` is that the change might occur in the nth activity. I cannot just keep on sending the data backwards using `onActivityResult`.

Also I cannot use static data because of no.of instances of the same Activity.

**Actual Scenario:**

Take the case of twitter, where I have **my followers list with an option to follow the users in the list** and I can select one person, go to his followers list where I will see a follow option for every user and so on.

*So, if I follow a user on some 10th list in the backstack, how will that get reflected in the 1st list which contains the same user? I mean it must change from follow to following.*

Comment: Use Interface this is better option

Comment: @DixitPatel. Can you please be more specific. Any link or code sample will do. Thankyou.

Comment: Why don't you check out the Observer pattern in some tutorials?

Comment: @StefandeBruijn you mean the Observer interface and Observable class in JAVA?

Comment: Yes you can use those to implement it. I assume they're present in Android too. It's an easy pattern to implement without extending those classes though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing your data somehow that is separate from the Activity. Typically this is done in via the sqlite database. The basic idea is when the use performs an action that you wish to record you save it somehow. More than likely in a database. Now that data is stored and accessible.

The next step is how to display updated data in an Activity. This is typically done in [`Activity#onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29). In onResume you would perform some actions that can retrieve the stored data and then update your display. `startActivityForResult` is used more or less for what its name implies. Starting another Activity with the intent of the callee providing the caller some data. It is not used to try to send data and state through the Activity stack.

Comment: But why database? I mean why should I store them in a database since the data usually changes often. Like say click to follow and unfollow. Also there will be huge data like I said list of followers of some 10 users..

Comment: I was just attempting to provide a very general overview about how to do about doing what you want. It's up to you to figure out how to store and retrieve your data. However, the main point is that the data storage is separate and distinct from the Activity. The Activities are used to manipulate and retrieve data. They are not used to store data.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use startActivityForResult then you need create static instance of each activity to make it accessible from any other activity.eg:-

public class xyz extends Activity
{

```
 private static xyz instance;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       ................
       ................
       instance = this; 

 }

 public static xyz getInstance(){
       return instance;
 }
```

}

Comment: How will I know which instance is returned? Also I cannot makeout which item has changed, I will end up changing everthing(recreating) in the activity.

Comment: I think you should make a static ArrayList<Activity> to maintain the reference of each instance of the same Activity.